# Is this possible to use CefSharp.WinForms in NUnit tests?

Tags: c#, nunit, cefsharp

Is this possible to properly use `CefSharp.Winforms.ChromiumWebBrowser` in NUnit?
Running the tests in Nunit Console Runner, using `CefSharp.WinForms 71.0.1` with `NUnit 3.10.1` I have been able to properly load CefSharp binaries using NUnit settings `--domain=None --inprocess`, and then to display some simple web page in ChromiumWebBrowser (with unresponsive UI though).

However, it looks like the ChromiumWebBrowser has not loaded correctly: `IsBrowserInitializedChanged` and `FrameLoadEnd` events are not fired at all.

I'm aware that CefSharp may apply app domain / process policies that contradict those imposed by NUnit.

My idea for a workaround is to move that ChromiumWebBrowser to a separate process (just for tests), communicate with that process using named pipe and run the assertions in Nunit tests project.

The questions here are:
 1. **Is this possible to display the ChromiumWebBrowser in the tests process, am I missing something?**
 2. **Are better workaround solutions applicable here?**

Comment: No matter if it possible or not: you should not create UI elements in unit tests at all. That is not what unit tests are designed for. For intergration tests you should use Selenium for example.

Comment: You can use the `Nunit Console Runner`, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/700#issuecomment-297209620
Little outdated, the concept is still valid.

Comment: @amaitland I am just using that approach

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Remember that WinForms isn't designed to be unit tested, so you'll have to jump though extra hoops. The Off screen version is better suited